# iOS App: incompatible pointer types

Tags: ios, pointers, core-data

in my iOS App I am trying to do following: In a ViewController there are several TextFields and a Save button. When the user taps on the Save button, the text of yearTextField  must be stored on a core data attribute (todoYear:int32).
This is the code for my Save method:

```
- (IBAction)SaveButtonAction:(id)sender {


    AppDelegate* appDelegate = [AppDelegate sharedAppDelegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext* context = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;

    NSManagedObject *favoriteThing = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"FavoriteThing" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSString *todoText = ToDoTextField.text;
    NSNumber *todoYear = [yearTextField.text intValue];
    NSNumber *todoMonth = [monthTextField.text intValue];
    NSNumber *todoDay = [dayTextField.text intValue];
    NSNumber *todoHour = [hourTextField.text intValue];
    NSNumber *todoMinute = [minuteTextField.text intValue];        
    NSString *todoUrgent = urgentTextField.text;
    NSString *todoColor = colorTextField.text;


    [favoriteThing setValue:todoText forKey:@"thingName"];
    [favoriteThing setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] forKey:@"displayOrder"];
    [favoriteThing setValue:todoYear forKey:@"todoYear"];
    [favoriteThing setValue:todoMonth forKey:@"todoMonth"];
    [favoriteThing setValue:todoDay forKey:@"todoDay"];
    [favoriteThing setValue:todoHour forKey:@"todoHour"];
    [favoriteThing setValue:todoMinute forKey:@"todoMinute"];
    [favoriteThing setValue:todoUrgent forKey:@"urgent"];
    [favoriteThing setValue:todoColor forKey:@"color"];             

    NSError *error;
    if(! [context save:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Whoopw,couldn't save:%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}
```

And this is the exception:

```
self    AddToDoViewController * 0x16578680  0x16578680
favoriteThing   FavoriteThing_FavoriteThing_ *  0x1650da90  0x1650da90
todoText    __NSCFString *  @"h"    0x1659f2b0
todoColor   __NSCFString *  @"Black"    0x16542070
todoUrgent  __NSCFString *  @"Not urgent"   0x165139e0
todoYear    NSNumber *  0x7dd   0x000007dd
todoMinute  NSNumber *  0x25    0x00000025
urgentTextField UITextField *   0x165bc2d0  0x165bc2d0
colorTextField  UITextField *   0x165b2de0  0x165b2de0
minuteTextField UITextField *   0x165b8380  0x165b8380
```

The attributes for 'todoText', 'todoColor', 'todourgent' are right, the error appears when reading the value for the 'todoYear' attribute. 
I don't know how to put the 'todoYear' value in the right way to be accepted correctly. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NSNumber`'s `numberWithInt` method:

```
NSNumber *todoYear = [NSNumber numberWithInt: [yearTextField.text intValue]];
NSNumber *todoMonth = [NSNumber numberWithInt: [monthTextField.text intValue]];
NSNumber *todoDay = [NSNumber numberWithInt: [dayTextField.text intValue]];
NSNumber *todoHour = [NSNumber numberWithInt: [hourTextField.text intValue]];
NSNumber *todoMinute = [NSNumber numberWithInt: [minuteTextField.text intValue]];
```

Or combine this all into an `NSDate`...

```
NSString *dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@-%@-%@ %@:%@:00 +0000",
    yearTextField.text, monthTextField.text, dayTextField.text,
    hourTextField.text, minuteTextField.text];
NSDate *todoDate = [NSDate dateWithString:dateString];
```

Comment: Thank you @nhgrif, that is the way to do it, no errors.I am very grateful.